# Azure AKS - splitting node pool over multiple Availability Zones

Tags: high-availability, azure-aks, azure-availability-set, availability-zone

I'm new to Azure so please bear with me! I'm looking to create a HA (99.99%) node pool for AKS. I am more familiar with AWS and availability zones, whereby I'd split the auto scaling group over 3 AZs and that would be that.

It appears that Azure have picked up on AZs and do offer them (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/azure-availability-zones-now-available-for-the-most-comprehensive-resiliency-strategy/) however, I don't see anyway to specify these parameters when creating an AKS cluster - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-create

Am I missing something here? If I use the availability set, there is only a 99.95% availability target which doesn't fulfill what I need. Basically I want to architect so that if an AZ fails in Azure my app keeps running...

Thanks!

Comment: It may be because AZs are so new in Azure? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/azure-availability-zones-ga/ they're only available in 2 regions!

Comment: What about "I'd split the auto scaling group over 3 AZs" mean? When you create AKS, there will be an Availability Set which I think the AZ you mean created for it.

Comment: In AWS you don't have the concept of Availability Set, you just have availability zones. When you set up an auto scaling group (think Virtual Machine Scale Sets) you can specify how many availability zones (Data Centres in one region) to split the cluster over, to cater for a Data Centre failure. Azure have just introduced Availability Zones to be able to provide a 99.99% SLA rather than the 99.95% of the Availability Sets. See the top link in my post. So, I was wondering if AKS could be configured to cluster over multiple Availability Zones rather than use Availability Sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately，Azure Availability Zones does not support AKS currently. It is just available for some regions and services. For details, see [support regions and services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-overview#regions-that-support-availability-zones).

Comment: I think worth to adjust this answer since it is under development and, probably, available this calendar year. See this, - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/914020-azure-kubernetes-service-aks/suggestions/36071860-support-multiple-availability-zones-for-ha-high-a

Comment: This answer is now out of date. See Manu Meyer's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Update: AKS with Availability Zone Support is now generally available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/availability-zones

But note that availability zone configuration can only be set during the cluster creation!